# How to parse log file to csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I want read my log file and put into csv file via Java. How would I parse the log file with these delimiters into csv file as below.

.log file:

```
2022-06-01 11:00:00 wt.nm=aa&wt.ti=t1&
2022-06-02 12:00:00 wt.nm=ab&wt.ti=t2&
2022-06-03 10:00:00 wt.nm=ac&wt.ti=t3&
```

date and time is separated by space, name and title separated by wt.nm=/wt.ti with & as end

CSV output:

```
date,time,name,title 
2022-06-01,11:00:00,aa,t1
2022-06-02,12:00:00,ab,t2
2022-06-03,10:00:00,ac,t3
```

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/ts/Desktop/test/src/0606.log"));
            FileWriter wb = new FileWriter("/Users/ts/Desktop/testcsv.csv");
            String str;
            while((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
                wb.write(str);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could specify a log record format as CSV. Even as second log file.

Answer (score 0):

Following will do the transformation.

**Answer 01**

You can use the following solution if the structure of the logs are fixed.

```java
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    str = str.replaceAll(" wt.nm=|&wt.ti=| ", ",").replace("&", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    wb.write(str);
}
```

**Answer 02**

If the structure is not fixed. You can use pattern matching to extract the relevant strings. Please refer to the following.

```java
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    
    String nm = "";
    String ti = "";
    // First Assuming Date and time willmbe always there.
    String [] parts =  str.split(" ");

    String tokenizingString = parts[2];
    String pattern1 = "wt.nm=";
    String pattern2 = "wt.ti=";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("&"));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    // Assumes the pattern occurs once, hence only getting the first matcher
    if (m.find()) {
        nm = m.group(1);
    }
    
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern2) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("&"));
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(str);
    
    if (m2.find()) {
        ti = m2.group(1);
    }
    
    String logEntry = parts[0] + "," + parts[1] + "," + nm + "," + ti;
    System.out.println(logEntry);
}
```

Comment: This is a decent solution, but it's (very) tightly coupled to the input data format. Any changes in the input data (such as adding a new name+value pair after `wt.ti`) would produce incorrect output.

Comment: @kaan Since you didn't mention anything about the changes that can happen for the inputs I didn't take that into account. I have updated my answer with a second solution.

Comment: I'm not OP, only pointing out that if input data changes then your original code solution ("Answer 01") would not behave as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

The format in your data (ignoring the leading date and time) looks like:

- `wt.nm` is always present
- `wt.ti` is always present
- `wt.nm` always appears before `wt.ti`
- there are never additional name+value pairs (beyond `wt.nm` and `wt.ti`)

However, the data has a more general pattern to it:

- one (or more) name+value pairs
- for each name+value pair, the name is separated from the value by `=`
- each name+value pair is separated from other pairs by `&`

Also, it's easy to imagine encountering additional name+value pairs (who says it will always be those same two forever? why not five name+values in a single line?), or perhaps the ordering changes (could `wt.ti` show up before `wt.nm`?).

The code below takes a general approach, working with the general pattern of your input data. I included some sample data to show how it works.

- the first input line – `"2022-06-01 11:00:00 wt.nm=aa&wt.ti=t1&"` – one of your original inputs
- the second line – `"2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=bb&"` – uses a different "name" altogether, and only has a single name+value pair (not two): `xxxxxxxxxxx=bb`
- the third line – `"2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=cc&yyyyyyyyyyyy=t3&zzzzzzzz=99&"` – includes a third name+value pair: `zzzzzzzz=99`. who says there will always be just two name+value pairs?

```
String[] lines = {
        "2022-06-01 11:00:00 wt.nm=aa&wt.ti=t1&",
        "2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=bb&",
        "2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=cc&yyyyyyyyyyyy=t3&zzzzzzzz=99&"
};
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println("original: " + line);
    String edit1 = line.replaceAll("&", " ");
    System.out.println("          " + edit1);

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(edit1);
    StringBuilder finalLine = new StringBuilder();
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println("   token: " + token);
        if (token.contains("=")) {
            int positionOfEqualsSign = token.indexOf("=");
            String value = token.substring(positionOfEqualsSign + 1);
            finalLine.append(value);
        } else {
            finalLine.append(token);
        }
        if (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            finalLine.append(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("   final: " + finalLine);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here's the output from that code, which includes a lot of extra output in order to be easier to follow:

```
original: 2022-06-01 11:00:00 wt.nm=aa&wt.ti=t1&
          2022-06-01 11:00:00 wt.nm=aa wt.ti=t1 
   token: 2022-06-01
   token: 11:00:00
   token: wt.nm=aa
   token: wt.ti=t1
   final: 2022-06-01,11:00:00,aa,t1

original: 2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=bb&
          2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=bb 
   token: 2022-06-01
   token: 11:00:00
   token: xxxxxxxxxxx=bb
   final: 2022-06-01,11:00:00,bb

original: 2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=cc&yyyyyyyyyyyy=t3&zzzzzzzz=99&
          2022-06-01 11:00:00 xxxxxxxxxxx=cc yyyyyyyyyyyy=t3 zzzzzzzz=99 
   token: 2022-06-01
   token: 11:00:00
   token: xxxxxxxxxxx=cc
   token: yyyyyyyyyyyy=t3
   token: zzzzzzzz=99
   final: 2022-06-01,11:00:00,cc,t3,99
```